# Why am I getting this error when I try to enter "npm start"?

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, open-source, npx

The Error looks likes this:

ERROR: You must supply a command.

Execute binaries from npm packages.

npx [options] [@version] [command-arg]...

npx [options] [-p|--package ]...  [command-arg]...

npx [options] -c ''

npx --shell-auto-fallback [shell]

A List of the script commands in npm packages.
"scripts": {
"start:nolint": "npx --yes create-react-play@latest -p && react-scripts start",
"start": "npx --yes create-react-play@latest -p && npm run lint && react-scripts start",
...
}

Link to the repository: https://github.com/prajwal18/react-play

I was trying to run the application. I installed all the dependencies. Followed the instructions described in the readme file of the project.
You can check that out here: https://github.com/prajwal18/react-play

I cannot find any simple explanation to the problem. Your help and feedback would be greately appreciated thank you.

Comment: Try `npm run start`